# Get records created within a certain time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm working on a project, and as part of it I want to be able to get all posts created within the last 7 days. I've tried:

```
  @weeks_posts = Post.where(date: Date.today)
    for i in 1..6
      @weeks_posts = @weeks_posts + Post.where(date: (Date.today).to_time - i.days)
    end
```

However this ends up returning an array which means I can't chain `.where` clauses to  it, which I need to do, it also seems quite inefficient.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to make it flexible:

```
scope :by_dates, ->(start_date, end_date) { Post.where(date: start_date..end_date) }

Post.by_dates(Date.today - 6.days, Date.today) # returns AR collection
```

Comment: I would prefer to use range in `where`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
Post.where(date: 1.week.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.now)
```